# Create Oozie Shared Library

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have Oozie installed and running. I am trying to run the example workflows, and got an error that I need to create the shared library. So I put the shared folder in HDFS under /user/{username}/share/lib. 

When I run: 
`bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://{host}:8020`, 
I get an error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder`

I have tried adding the htrace core jar into my libext folder of oozie and that gives me a Java Servlet error. Did I miss a step? I cannot seem to find anything related to this.

Comment: Can u post your workflow and properties file

Answer (score -1):

It ended up being an issue with my /libext directory. I went back and added the ext js zip and then found all ".jar" files in my hadoop directory. After filtering out the overlap of tomcat, etc with the Oozie UI, i was able to get an example workflow running!

Comment: I couldn't find the relation between the problem and the solution